# Add user role to request in Spring MVC Test Framework

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test-mvc

Started studying Spring Test MVC Framework at the office today, it looks handy, but facing some serious trouble right off the bat. Spent a few hours googling, but couldn't find anything related to my issue.

Here's my very simple test class:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebAppContext.class)
public class ControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void processFetchErrands() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/errands.do?fetchErrands=true"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(model().attribute("errandsModel", allOf(
                   hasProperty("errandsFetched", is(true)),
                   hasProperty("showReminder", is(false)))));
    }
}
```

The test reaches the following controller, but fails on first `if` clause thanks to not being authorized properly.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="fetchErrands")
public String processHaeAsioinnit(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap modelMap,
                                  @ModelAttribute(ATTR_NAME_MODEL) @Valid ErrandsModel model,
                                  BindingResult result, JopoContext ctx) {
  if (request.isUserInRole(Authority.ERRANDS.getCode())) {
    return Page.NO_AUTHORITY.getCode();
  }

  [...]
}
```

How do I add a user role for the `MockHttpServletRequest` that gets created by `MockMvcRequestBuilders.post()`, so that I can get past the authority check on my controller?

I know `MockHttpServletRequest` has a method `addUserRole(String role)`, but since `MockMvcRequestBuilders.post()` returns a `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`, I never get my hands on the `MockHttpServletRequest` and thus cannot call that method.

Checking the Spring source, `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` has no methods related to user roles, nor is the `MockHttpServletRequest.addUserRole(String role)` ever called in that class, so I have no idea how to tell it to add a user role into the request.

All I can think of is adding a custom filter to filter chain and calling a custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper` from there that provides an implementation of `isUserInRole()`, but that seems a little extreme for such a case. Surely the framework should offer something more practical?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I found an [easier way](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html#running-as-a-user-in-spring-mvc-test-with-annotations)

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "username", roles={"ADMIN"})
public void testGetMarkupAgent() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(get("/myurl"))
            .andExpect([...]);
}
```

You might need the following maven entry

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Depending on you security implementation, you may use 'authorities = {"ADMIN"}' instead of roles.

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC Test has the principal() method that allows to mock the request credentials for cases like this. This is an example of a test where some mock credentials are set:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class MobileGatewayControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;  

@Autowired
private Principal principal;

@Autowired
private MockServletContext servletContext;

@Before 
public void init()  {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}


@Test
public void testExampleRequest() throws Exception {

    servletContext.declareRoles("ROLE_1");

    mockMvc.perform(get("/testjunit")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .principal(principal))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[1]").value("test"));
}

}
```

and this is an example of how to create a mock principal:

```
@Configuration
public class SetupTestConfig {

@Bean
public Principal createMockPrincipal()  {
    Principal principal = Mockito.mock(Principal.class);
    Mockito.when(principal.getName()).thenReturn("admin");  
    return principal;
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't add the name into roles, nor does our authentication solution add the role into the principal's name. What point is there to a unit test that tests something that doesn't happen in production?

Comment: That's right I've edited the answer, one way of making request.isUserInRole() work in a spring MVC test is to inject the MockServletContext itself instead of the MockHttpServletRequest and declare some roles as above.

Comment: Did you forget the injection part? Just adding an instance variable without assigning it won't fix this.

Comment: I've put autowiring for the instance variable servletContext in the test @Autowired private MockServletContext servletContext, you mean the call to servletContext.declareRoles() ?

Comment: I've tested here locally and it works, request.isUserInRole("ROLE_1") returns true inside the controller.

Comment: What kind of autowiring configuration did you use? Adding it as a bean to my config leaves the roles still empty inside the controller.

Comment: Ah, it fails if you define a configuration for `servletContext` autowiring, but magically works, if you omit the config. How logical, when everything else works the other way around. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a [RequestPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/RequestPostProcessor.html) to configure the [MockHttpServletRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) before it's used in the request.

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/")
                    .with(new RoleRequestPostProcessor("some role"));

class RoleRequestPostProcessor implements RequestPostProcessor {
    private final String role;

    public RoleRequestPostProcessor(final String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(final MockHttpServletRequest request) {
        request.addUserRole(role);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also an easy, alternative way of setting up specific user role for a single request. It might be handy if you want to perform only a single operation as an authorized user (like set up the test fixture), and then check if user with different role can perform certain operation:

```
ResultActions registerNewUserAsAdmin(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    final SignUpRequest signUpPayload = new SignUpRequest(username, password);

    final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder registerUserRequest = post(SIGN_UP_URL)
        .with(user("admin").roles("ADMIN"))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(signUpPayload));

    return mockMvc.perform(registerUserRequest);
}
```

See [SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/test/web/servlet/request/SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Authority instead of Roles, then grant the authority in the request like below.

```
mockMvc.perform(
            put(REQUEST_URL).param(PARM, VALUE)
                    .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(USERNAME).authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))                        
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    )
```